# How to access data object from a nested array

Tags: vega-lite, observablehq

I am using ObservableHQ and vega lite API to do data visualizations and have faced a problem I can't figure out.
The problem is that, I would like to access data object from the following data structure,

Array

- Array
- Array

  - Item
  - Item
- Array

As you can see in my bad drawing, I have a multidimensional array and would like to access a specific array from the main array. How can I do that using Vegalite API?

```
vl.markCircle({
  thickness: 4,
  bandSize: 2
})
.data(diff[0])
.encode(
vl.x().fieldQ("mins").scale({ domain: [-60, 60] }),
vl.color().fieldN('type').scale({ range: ['#636363', '#f03b20'] }),
)
.config({bandSize: 10})
.width(600)
.height(40)
.render()
```

Thank you,

Comment: If you want to refer to the second child array, and the parent is call `data`, you could write `data[1]`. You could pass that into Vega-Lite or anything else. But maybe you're asking something harder! Could you post a link to a notebook with an example of this issue?

Comment: Can you try the following questions first if they are helpful: [q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467415/use-data-as-arrays-instead-of-table-for-vega-lite) and [q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62228654/using-2d-array-data-instead-of-table-in-vega-lite). Also add some reproducible or sample code in which we can check what you are actually facing.

Comment: @Toph, your answer helped me and now I can access a specific array in the complete 2D array. Unfortunately, I can't post the notebook as it's a research paper. However, I can post the code for the chart.

Comment: My next question or part 2 of my initial question is, how can automate the loop through the array? Like I want the piece of code further up to draw the same chart for all array in my main array. 

So that I don't have to manually change "data[1]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I’m assuming that you’re trying to automatically chart *all* of the nested arrays (separately), not just one of them. And based on your chart code, I’m assuming that your data looks sorta like this:

```js
const diff = [
  [
    { mins: 38, type: "Type B" },
    { mins: 30, type: "Type B" },
    { mins: 28, type: "Type A" },
    …
  ],
  [
    { mins: 20, type: "Type B" },
    { mins: 17, type: "Type A" },
    { mins: 19, type: "Type A" },
    …
  ],
  …
];
```

First, flatten all the arrays into one big array, and record which array each came from with a new `array` property on the item object, with [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). If each child array represents, say, a different city, or a different year, or a different person collecting the data, you could replace `array: i` with something more meaningful about the data.

```js
const flat = diff.flatMap((arr, i) => arr.map((d) => ({ ...d, array: i })));
```

Then use Vega-Lite’s “faceting” ([documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/facet.html), [Observable tutorial and examples](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/layers-facets-concat?collection=@observablehq/observable-for-vega-lite#facet)) to make split the chart into sections, one for each value of `array: i`, with shared scales. This just adds one line to your example:

```js
vl
  .markCircle({
    thickness: 4,
    bandSize: 2
  })
  .data(flat)
  .encode(
    vl.row().fieldN("array"), // this line is new
    vl
      .x()
      .fieldQ("mins")
      .scale({ domain: [-60, 60] }),
    vl
      .color()
      .fieldN("type")
      .scale({ range: ["#636363", "#f03b20"] })
  )
  .config({ bandSize: 10 })
  .width(600)
  .height(40)
  .render()
```

[Here’s an Observable notebook with examples of this working.](https://observablehq.com/d/1a2e034b8c32171a) As I show there at the bottom, you can also map over your array to make a totally separate chart for each nested array.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for.